# Flutter cannot find SQFLite databases path in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, ubuntu-20.04, sqflite, flutter-desktop

I am working on a notes app and using VS code in Ubuntu 20.04 I have integrated the SQFLite and path plugins but I am getting the exception

```
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite))
```

Here is the integration of plugins

```
sqflite: ^2.0.2
path: ^1.8.0
```

These are the imports for these plugins

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
```

And here is the way I am accessing databases paths

```
Database db = await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), "notes.db"),
    onCreate: ((db, version) async {
  await db.execute('''
  CREATE TABLE $tableName (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    $col1Name TEXT,
    $col2Name TEXT,
    $col3Name DATE
  )
  ''');
}), version: 1);
```

I have tried `flutter clean` but it is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqflite` plugin is not supported on linux, you need to use the `sqflite_common_ffi` package that works both for flutter and dart VM on linux. More information [here](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/using_ffi_instead_of_sqflite.md)